# How to cut some text in bash

Tags: bash

After cat my file, I got following output:

```
pm/or { distribution: 'Old disctribution ', version_1: '6.5 (New)', version_2: '2.36' }
```

I would like to cut from this file only for example distribution name: Old disctribution or for example only version_2: 2.36.

As output I would like to get:
Old disctribution

Could someone help how can to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to cut it with `'` as a delimiter
Something like:

```
cut -d \' -f 2,6 myfile.txt > output.txt
```

I just try this and it works properly

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F\' '{ print $2 }' file
```

Or

```
awk -F\' '/pm/or {/ { print $2 }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks vaguely like you are trying to parse JSON.  If your file format is almost, but not entirely JSON, perhaps your best bet is to reshape it into proper JSON, then use a proper JSON tool.

```
 sed 's%^pm/or %%;s%\([_A-Za-z0-9]*\):%"\1":%g' myfile.txt | jq '.distribution'
```

The `jq` tool is available from http://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: The second command in the `sed` script is not completely correct; it will mess with your data if you have quoted strings containing text just before a colon.  Your sample data looks simple enough that I felt I could cut this particular corner rather safely.

Comment: It's probably not JSON. JSON don't use single quotes.

Comment: Hmmm, true.  I should fix that, too; but then this is already becoming slightly more complex than I like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the `distribution` key with `awk` like this:

```
awk -F"'" '{for(;i<=NF;i++) {if($i ~ /distribution: $/) print $(i+1)}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash parameter expansion is also available from within a script to handle extracting the desired text:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=`cat dat/catfile.txt`                     # read file into temp
temp="${temp##*ion: \'}"                       # remove begin to 'ion: \''
echo "string '${temp%%[^a-z]\',*version*}'"    # remove end to first version
```

**input:**

```
$ cat dat/catfile.txt
pm/or { distribution: 'Old disctribution ', version_1: '6.5 (New)', version_2: '2.36' }
```

**output:**

```
$ cutcat.sh
string 'Old disctribution'
```

(spelling as in original)